# Image Uploading using bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, image-uploading

I have created an image uploader using the file upload option in Bootstrap. I want to upload images to a separate folder and keep the path name in the database. When I click the upload button the code does not show any error message but it doesn't works. Could you please help me to solve this problem? I have attached my code here:

**image_upload_form_ui.php**

```
     <form id="fileupload" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="phpscripts/test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

    <div class="control-group "> <!-- start of image -->
          <label class="control-label">Avatar</label>
      <div class="controls">
          <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-camera"></i></span>

          <!-- file upload-->
            <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">

              <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image"/></div>
            <div>
        <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
        <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span> 
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="204800" />
        <input type="file" name="image" /></span>
          <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
          </div>
            </div>
          <!--end of file upload -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end of image -->

  <div class="control-group"> <!-- start of buttons -->
    <label class="control-label"></label>
        <div class="controls">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Upload</button>

        </div>

  </div> <!-- end of buttons -->

</form>
```

here is my test.php

```
<?php
include "dbConnect.php";

//connect to the database
dbConnect();

$path = "uploads/";

$valid_formats = array("jpg","jpeg", "png", "gif", "bmp");

if(isset($_POST['image']))

        {echo "1";  
            $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $size = $_FILES['image']['size'];


if(strlen($name))
    {
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
    {
if($size<(2048*2048))
    {
        $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
        $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
    {

        mysql_query("UPDATE tutor SET avatar='$actual_image_name' WHERE userName='Isuru'");
        echo "Hari";                        
    }else
        echo die(mysql_error());

    }else

        echo "exceed the file size";        

    }else
        echo "Not a valid format";      


    }else
        echo "no file is selected";     


        }


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in `test.php` is checking the `$_POST` variable to see if a file was submitted via the form, but you probably want to be checking `$_FILES`. Check out the [PHP documentation on file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for more information.

Try changing:

```
if(isset($_POST['image']))
```

to

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
```